# Using Central Limit Theorem to find a probability for the sample mean

Tags: probability

Let $X_1, X_2, \ldots , X_{10000}$ be i.i.d. Expo(1). Let $\bar X_{10000} = \sum X_i/10000$. Use CLT to
 $10000$ estimate $P(0.893 < \bar X_{10000} < 1.003)$

I know how to find probability using CLT given mean and variance, but I'm not familiar with this form.

Comment: It is widely known that the expected value of $X_n$ is the expected value of $X$ and its variance is the common variance, divided by $n$. Hence $X_{10000}$ is $N(1,1/10000)$-distributed.

Comment: You have used notation $X_{10000}$ for the last observation and for the sample mean. I think you mean $\bar X_{10000} = \frac{1}{10000}\sum_{i=1}^{10000} X_i,$ so I'm putting a bar on the symbol for the mean, and cleaning up the expression for the probability. If that's not what you intended, then please re-edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $X_i,\; i = 1, 2, \dots, 10000$ are independently distributed as
$\mathsf{Exp}(1),$ then $E(\bar X) = 1,\, Var(\bar X) = 1/10000,$
and $SD(\bar X) = 1/\sqrt{10000} = 1/100.$

By the central limit theorem, $\bar X$ is approximately
$\mathsf{Norm}(\mu = 1,\, \sigma = 0.01).$

From R statistical software, $P(0.893 < \bar X < 1.003) = 0.61791.$

```
diff(pnorm(c(0.893, 1.003), 1, .01))
## 0.6179114
```

I suppose you are expected to evaluate the probability by standardizing
and using a printed normal table. Because approximations may be necessary in
using printed tables, you may get a slightly different answer. Here is
a start toward using a normal table:

$$P(0.893 < \bar X < 1.003) =
P\left(\frac{0.893 - 1}{0.01} < \frac{\bar X - \mu}{\sigma}
< \frac{1.003 - 1}{0.01}\right)
=P(-10.7 < Z < 0.3),$$

where $Z$ has a standard normal distribution. Because $-10.7$ is so far from 0
you won't find a useful value for the lower end of the interval in a printed table. But the probability
you want is essentially $P(Z < 0.3).$ There is almost no probability in a standard normal distribution below $-10.7.$

*Note:* The exact distribution of $\bar X$ is $\mathsf{Gamma}(shape=10000, rate=10000)$ so the exact probability to four places, *not using the Central Limit Theorem*, is 0.6191. The approach of an exponential mean to normal (according to the CLT)
is slow because the exponential distribution is extremely skewed, but
$n = 10000$ is a very large sample size, so the CLT gives a useful approximation.

```
diff(pgamma(c(.893,1.003), 10000, 10000))
## 0.6190677
```